# Derived class offset calculation in boost::serialization. Is it valid?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

`boost::serialization` contains [this code](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/blob/76df6df23ff9ad081099a0288e943535626aeb08/include/boost/serialization/void_cast.hpp#L187):

```
reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(
    static_cast<Derived *>(
        reinterpret_cast<Base *>(1 << 20)
    )
) - (1 << 20)
```

Its purpose is to calculate an offset between base and derived classes. Is this code free of undefined behaviour?

---

The reason why I am asking is that ASAN+UBSAN complain. For example, this code

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo { public: virtual void foo() {} };
class Base { public: virtual void base() {} };
class Derived: public Foo, public Base {};

int main()
{
    std::cout <<
       (reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(
            static_cast<Derived *>(
                reinterpret_cast<Base *>(1 << 20)
            )
       ) - (1 << 20));
}
```

compiled as (gcc version 9.2.1)

```
g++ -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g main.cpp
```

produces this output

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==72613==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x0000000ffff8 (pc 0x0000004012d9 bp 0x7ffd5b3eecf0 sp 0x7ffd5b3eece0 T0)
==72613==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x4012d8 in main main.cpp:13
    #1 0x7f74a90d5f42 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x23f42)
    #2 0x40112d in _start (/home/.../a.out+0x40112d)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV main.cpp:13 in main
```

Is it a false-positive or does this code really have problems?

---

**Update 09.12.2019:** based on Filipp's proposal and my experiments, this code seems to work and does not produce any warnings:

```
std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Derived)>::type data;
reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data)
  - reinterpret_cast<char*>(
        static_cast<Base*>(
            reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(&data)));
```

Does anybody see any problems with this snippet? If not, I would propose it to `boost`.

---

**Update 16.12.2019:** the fix [was merged](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/commit/489eef0e178574c9cd8f2e508da6261aea9b0093) to `boost::serialization` `develop` branch.

Comment: `aligned_storage` is C++11. Does boost serialization require at least that version of C++? If not, I recommend trying another approach. Does ubsan complain if the buffer is not aligned?

Comment: Good point, but `boost` has its own `aligned_storage`. I will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by another answer, the problem is that `(1 << 20)` isn't the address of any object. Using a `char[]` that could in principle store a `Derived` seems to work around the problem:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo { public: virtual void foo() {} };
class Base { public: virtual void base() {} };
class Derived: public Foo, public Base {};

int main() {
    alignas (Derived) char const buffer[sizeof(Derived)] = {};
    Derived const* const derived = reinterpret_cast<Derived const*>(buffer);
    Base const* const base = derived;
    ptrdiff_t const delta =
        reinterpret_cast<char const*>(derived) -
        reinterpret_cast<char const*>(base);
    ::printf("%td\n", delta);
    return 0;
}
```

> Is it a false-positive or does this code really have problems?

According to a strict reading of the standard the code does exhibit UB, so in that sense it is not a *false* positive. In practice, both boost authors and compiler writers agree this is just pointer math, so it should do the right thing anyway.

Edit: Unless one of the bases involved is `virtual`. Then the cast would try to read the offset from the vtable.

Edit 2: Using `nullptr` produces 0. Changed to using local aligned buffer.

Comment: Just checked and the outputs are different. This code prints 0 while the `boost` version prints -8. I think the problem is in `nullptr` and this is the reason why `boost` uses a magic number.

Comment: _"both boost authors and compiler writers agree this is just pointer math, so it should do the right thing anyway"_ I wouldn't be so sure about that. I keep seeing this assumption, but it doesn't necessarily hold. You're not programming bare metal - you're writing in abstractions.

Comment: Virtual inheritance is one case where code like this is definitely broken. If `Derived` inherits virtually from `Base` and is not `final`, then `static_cast` would try to read the object at that address and fail spectacularly.

Answer (score 2):

```
reinterpret_cast<Base *>(1 << 20)
```

This is not a valid pointer.

`static_cast`ing it requires evaluating it, which has undefined behaviour.

This is an interesting "trick" but it doesn't seem to be well-defined, and that's borne out by the results of the `-fsanitize` options.

[This does not seem to be unusual for `boost::serialization`](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/issues/182).